# Handle huge amount of data in node.js through stdin

Tags: node.js, stream, stdin, readline

Old question title:

"**node.js readline form net.Socket (process.stdin) cause error: heap out of memory (conversion of net.Socket Duplex to Readable stream)**"

... I've changed it because nobody answered and it seems like important question in node.js ecosystem.

Question is how to solve problem of "heap out of memory" error when reading line by line from huge stdin? Error is not happening when you dump stdout to file (eg: test.log) and read to 'readline' interface through fs.createReadStream('test.log').

Looks like process.stdin is not Readable stream as it is mentioned here:
https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin

To reproduce the issue I've created two scripts. First is to just generate huge amount of data (a.js file):

```
// a.js
// loop in this form generates about 7.5G of data
// you can check yourself running:
// node a.js > test.log && ls -lah test.log
// will return
// -rw-r--r--  1 sd  staff   7.5G 31 Jan 22:29 test.log
for (let i = 0 ; i < 8000000 ; i += 1 ) {
  console.log(`${i} ${".".repeat(1000)}\n`);
}
```

The script to consume this through bash pipe with readline (b.js file):

```
const fs = require('fs');

const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin, // doesn't work
  //input: fs.createReadStream('test.log'), // works
});

let s;

rl.on('line', line => {

  // deliberaty commented out to demonstrate that issue
  // has nothing to do beyond readline and process.stdin

  // s = line.substring(0, 7);
  //
  // if (s === '100 ...' || s === '400 ...' || s === '7500000') {
  //
  //   process.stdout.write(`${line}\n`);
  // }
});

rl.on('error', e => {

  console.log('general error', e)
})
```

Now when you run;

```
node a.js | node b.js
```

it will result with error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

but if you swap

```
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
});
```

to

```
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('test.log')
});
```

and run

```
node a.js > test.log
node b.js
```

everything works fine

Problem comes down actually to how to convert net.Socket to fully functional Readable stream?, if it is possible at all.

## Edit:

Basically my problem is that it seems like it is not possible to handle huge amount of data from stdin as a stream which is natural for Unix style pipes. So despite the fact node.js is brilliant in handling streams you can't write program that would handle huge amount of data through unix style pipes.

It would be totally not necessary in some cases to dump data to the hard drive and only after handle it with fs.createReadStream('test.log') only because of this limitation.

I thought that streams are all about handling huge amount of data (among other use cases) on the flight without saving it on hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can always treat `process.stdin` as a normal NodeJS stream and handle the reading your self:

```js
const os = require('os');

function onReadLine(line) {
    // do stuff with line
    console.info(line);
}

// read input and split into lines
let BUFF = '';
process.stdin.on('data', (buff) => {
    const content = buff.toString('utf-8');
    for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++){
        if (content[i] === os.EOL) {
            onReadLine(BUFF);
            BUFF = '';
        } else {
            BUFF += content[i];
        }
    }
});

// flush last line
process.stdin.on('end', () => {
    if (BUFF.length > 0) {
        onReadLine(BUFF);
    }
});
```

Example:

```sh
// unix
cat ./somefile.txt | node ./script.js

// windows
Start-Process -FilePath "node" -ArgumentList @(".\script.js")  -RedirectStandardInput .\somefile.txt -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Comment: Your solution is not really solving the problem, you're using cat ./somefile.txt instead of node a.js on input - that's the real reason why your solution works. The problem was correctly explained by @sergey-pogodin

Comment: @stopsopa The answer addresses the question title: "NodeJS cannot handle huge amount of data" and demonstrates that it does handle any kind of data streamed to it via regular OS level pipes. The concern that using a file instead of another process output is reason of success, is invalid. The "source" of handler process input data is irrelevant to its working. You can replace `cat ./somefile.txt` in above example with any other command/process that generates text lines.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not input data size, not Node, but a faulty design of your data generator: it does not implement pausing/resuming data generation on request of consumer output stream. Instead of just pushing data to `console.log(..)` you should correctly interact with standard output stream, and correctly handle `pause` and `resume` signals from that stream.

The file input stream created by `fs.createReadStream()` is implemented properly, and it does pause/resumes as necessary, thus does not crash the code.

Comment: cat bigfile.txt | node b.js instead node a.js | node b.js helped - you're right, thanks